# Checking a range of dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would like a formula that will return Yes only if a range of cells in the same row all have dates in the future, and if five other cells in the same row have the value "Yes".

I tried to just check the dates first and I suspected this wouldn't work but I tried

```
=IF(P3:Y3>TODAY(), "Yes", "No")
```

which returned #VALUE! because I can't use ranges in that way. I *could* use:

```
=IF(AND(K3="Yes", [LMN blah blah], O3="Yes", P3>TODAY(), Q3>TODAY(), T3>TODAY()[... etc] ), "Yes", "No")
```

but if ever I need to do this for a much larger range of cells, is there a more convenient way to run the same check on all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) works for me -

```
=IF(AND(A1:A3>TODAY(),B1:B3="Yes"), "Yes", "No")
```

Type it and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shft</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> - you will see curly brackets appear.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've done supposedly "advanced" Excel courses but I didn't know about array functions until now. I'm sure I'll have plenty of use for them.